# creating object using new Operator in java

Tags: class, object, set, hashset

Here

> set s = new HashSet();

Here what does the new operator does exactly. 
Is that creates the object for the class **`Set`** or for the object for the constructors class **`HashSet`**. why we want to write these types of codes. and is that any alternative option to create a object for a class without using new keyword.

Please explain me clearly i am new to java programming...

Comment: Set is an interface and HasSet is a child implementation. You should search for "inheritance in java" or rather "Polymorphism in java" . http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutor5.htm

Answer (score 0):

"new" creates a new "instance" of the class "HashSet".

Part of "creation" is to invoke the class's constructor.

In Java (unlike other languages, for example C++ or Javascript), "new" is the only way to create a new object.

Here's a bit more info:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: No, it creates an instance of the class `HashSet`. `Set` is the type of the *variable*, and is an interface, not a class.

Comment: is the **HashSet()** constructor gives any return type to the **Set**. and can you explain in deeper about using the new keyword in interface class, inherited class and abstract class..

Comment: There's no easy, one-line answer.  You can't "create" an interface.  But you *can* create a class that *implements* an interface.  Java "interfaces" are a wonderful construct that solve a lot of problems ... including avoid much of the nastiness of "multiple inheritance" in C++.  Google for "Java class object interface abstract class variable new" and other search words.  Or refer to any of the above links.  Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" is also a very good book (also available on-line).

Comment: Thanks paulsm4 i will try the **`Thinking in java`** but there only 3rd edition for free is that book enough to study.

Comment: For the conceptual background you're looking for: yes, absolutely yes.  Enjoy!